# SQLite Xamarin.Forms PCL errors on Android

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, cross-platform

I am trying to build an sqlite database on xamarin(C#) in pcl project. I am following [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-xamarinforms-and-sqlite--cms-23020) tutorial. On the Android Implementation (Step5) i get these errors:

Error   CS0104  'Environment' is an ambiguous reference between 'Android.OS.Environment' and 'System.Environment'   AlarmSQLite.Android c:\users\thomas\source\repos\AlarmSQLite\AlarmSQLite\AlarmSQLite.Android\SQLite_Android.cs  30  Active

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace 'SQLite' (are you missing an assembly reference?)  AlarmSQLite.Android c:\users\thomas\source\repos\AlarmSQLite\AlarmSQLite\AlarmSQLite.Android\SQLite_Android.cs  33  Active

I use VisualStudio2017. I tried to remove .Net and added System.Environment but i get more and new errors. 
My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using SQLite;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AlarmSQLite.Droid;
using System.IO;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]

namespace AlarmSQLite.Droid
{
public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
{
    public SQLite_Android() { }



    public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var dbName = "AlarmDB.db3";
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, dbName);

        var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
        var connection = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(platform, path);

        return connection;
    }

}
}
```

Everything is the same with the tutorial. What am i doing wrong? Thank you!

New Errors:

Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Platform' does not exist in the namespace 'SQLite' (are you missing an assembly reference?) AlarmSQLite.Android C:\Users\Thomas\source\repos\AlarmSQLite\AlarmSQLite\AlarmSQLite.Android\SQLite_Android.cs  33  Active

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection' to 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection'   AlarmSQLite.Android C:\Users\Thomas\source\repos\AlarmSQLite\AlarmSQLite\AlarmSQLite.Android\SQLite_Android.cs  36  Active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error CS0104:** 
Environment comes from 'Android.OS.Environment' as well as 'System.Environment' so giving you and ambiguity issue. Just Prepend System to the Environment.

```
var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

**Error CS0234:** Seems like you haven't added [SQLite-Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/) Nuget Package. You have to add this in your PCL as well as in Android project and build project again.

**Error CS0234 &  CS0029:** Make sure you added following two nuget packages in android and pcl projects.

[image: Sqlite.Net PCL]
[image]

Then, instead of using Sqlite, try to use Sqlite.Net.

[image]

Your Final Code should Look :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AlarmSQLite.Droid;
using System.IO;
using SQLite.Net;
using SQLite.Net.Async;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]

namespace AlarmSQLite.Droid
{
public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
{
    public SQLite_Android() { }



    public SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var dbName = "AlarmDB.db3";
        var documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, dbName);

        var platform = new SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid.SQLitePlatformAndroid();
        var connection = new SQLiteConnection(platform, path);

        return connection;
    }

}
}
```

Do not forget to adjust your interface for the same. It should be like:

```
SQLiteConnection GetConnection():
```

**Note**: You can omit Sqlite.Net.Async PCL reference if you don't need it.

Comment: The errors solved but i get new errors. 
Platform(same error as .Net) and on return connection the method has to be .Net. but when i do that i have a problem with the interface that makes the connection

Comment: I could see only two errors in your post. Please mention those new errors.

Comment: i updated my answer. You are using "SQLite" reference instead of "SQlite.Net".